# Extra subquery generated on left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, left-join

I wrote a method to perform a left join in LINQ, using the standard `GroupJoin`/`SelectMany`/`DefaultIfEmpty` approach:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> left,
    IEnumerable<TRight> right,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector)
{
    var paramL = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft), "l");
    var paramR = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight), "r");
    var paramRs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<TRight>), "rs");

    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLeft, IEnumerable<TRight>, IEnumerable<TResult>>>(
       Expression.Call(
           typeof(Enumerable),
           "Select",
           new [] { typeof(TRight), typeof(TResult) },
           Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "DefaultIfEmpty", new[] { typeof(TRight) }, paramRs),
           Expression.Lambda<Func<TRight, TResult>>(
               Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, paramL, paramR),
               paramR)),
       paramL,
       paramRs
   );

    return left
        .GroupJoin(
            right,
            leftKeySelector,
            rightKeySelector,
            expr)
        .SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

I tested it thus:

```
var q = myDB.PurchaseOrderHeaders
    .LeftJoin(
        myDB.PurchaseOrderLines,
        po => po.PurchaseOrderGUID,
        line => line.PurchaseOrderGUID,
        (po, line) => new { PO = po, Line = line }
    );

var e = q.AsEnumerable();
```

I expected SQL like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[PurchaseOrderGUID], ..., [t1].[PurchaseOrderLineGUID], ...
FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderHeader] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLine] AS [t1]
    ON [t0].[PurchaseOrderGUID] = [t1].[PurchaseOrderGUID]
```

But got this:

```
SELECT [t0].[PurchaseOrderGUID], ..., [t2].[test], [t2].[PurchaseOrderLineGUID], ...
FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderHeader] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[PurchaseOrderLineGUID], ...
    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLine] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON [t0].[PurchaseOrderGUID] = [t2].[PurchaseOrderGUID]
```

The difference is the subquery with `SELECT 1 as [test]`. Why is it generating this? Is it likely to have any significant effect on performance? If so, can I modify the query to eliminate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know very much about LINQ. The below is based on my knowledge of SQL, and an educated inference about what LINQ is trying to do.)

> Why is it generating this?

I presume that the purpose of `1 AS [test]` is to give LINQ a clear, simple, consistent, and unambiguous way to distinguish "no matching records in `PurchaseOrderLine`" from "one matching record in `PurchaseOrderLine`". You might think that you could distinguish these by examining `PurchaseOrderLineGUID` and the other fields, and that's probably true in your case; but in the general case, what would happen if a `LEFT JOIN` successfully joined to a record, but all of the fields selected from that record were null? (In your case, that's not possible, because `PurchaseOrderLineGUID` is (I assume) non-nullable, but does LINQ know that? Though for that matter, even without knowing which table-columns are non-nullable, a human query-writer could have avoided the subquery by using `[t2].[PurchaseOrderGuid] AS [test]` in the top-level field-list, since the `ON` clause prevents the possibility that `[t2].[PurchaseOrderGuid]` will be null if the match was successful; but I'm not sure how obvious that is to LINQ.)

> Is it likely to have any significant effect on performance?

There *shouldn't* be any; because `1 AS [test]` isn't used anywhere that could really affect query semantics (e.g., in a `WHERE` or `ON` or `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause), SQL Server should be able to perform "predicate pushdown" to (in a sense) move the `ON` condition into the subquery, and perform a regular indexed hash-join between `PurchaseOrderHeader` and `PurchaseOrderLine` to determine which records it needs. The `1 AS [test]` would then only be added when it's assembling the result-set, for the `PurchaseOrderLine` records that are actually selected.

(I say this in part because I know that SQL Server is good at predicate pushdowns — [even in the rare cases where that turns out to be a bad thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dfurman/archive/2009/12/02/query-performance-scalar-udfs-and-predicate-pushdown.aspx) — and in part because, as noted above, LINQ *could* have avoided creating the subquery in this case. I imagine that the LINQ team knows what they're doing, and if they thought the subquery could have a performance penalty, I'm guessing that LINQ would try harder to determine whether a given case really requires the subquery. Since LINQ doesn't bother, it's presumably because it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

[LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) helps solve those problems. The following extension creates nice sql.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
    IQueryable<TInner> inner,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> result) {

    return outer.GroupJoin(
            inner, 
            outerKeySelector, 
            innerKeySelector, 
            (a, b) => new { a, b }).AsExpandable()
        .SelectMany(
            z => z.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
            (z, b) => result.Invoke(z.a, b));
}
```